# php preg_replace word to link, but word can't be already as part of anchor

Tags: php, preg-replace, preg-replace-callback

I have some HTML content:

```
<p>
Nunc nulla tincidunt metus sed eros auctor sagittis. Sed malesuada, mi et ornare 
molestie, urna dui 
<a href="http://google.com/" title="condimentum nulla">condimentum nulla, ut luctus</a> nisl ipsum ut dui. 
Praesent aliquam velit quis neque congue consectetur <b>nulla</b>. 
Curabitur turpis risus, malesuada nec volutpat sit amet, auctor porta velit.
</p>
```

And i want to replace all "nulla" words to links, but only if "nulla" is not a part of another link url or other HTML parameter (title, alt). In above example script should only replace first and last "nulla" word, and others leave as is. I'm stuck with this regular expression, but it doesn't work how i want:

```
/[^<a]+[^>]*nulla[^<\/a>]/
```

Comment: The `[^<...]` is on the right track, but wrong syntax.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Regular expression to match keyword outside HTML tag <a>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7798829/php-regular-expression-to-match-keyword-outside-html-tag-a), possibly in conjunction with [php regex to match outside of html tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7891771/php-regex-to-match-outside-of-html-tags)

Comment: Thanks, this solution works for me:
$str = preg_replace('~nulla(?!(?>[^<]*(?:<(?!/?a\b)[^<]*)*)</a>)~i',
                    '<a href="novo-mega-link.php">$0</a>', $str);

Answer (score 3):

Final solution that works as it should:

```
$str = preg_replace('~\bnulla\b(?!(?>[^<]*(?:<(?!/?a\b)[^<]*)*)</a>)~iu', '<a href="novo-mega-link.php">$0</a>', $str);
```

Comment: Let us know when it breaks, looks fragile. Probably better use a HTML parser_

Comment: What do you mean "HTML parser_"?

Comment: Just what the term suggests: A parser for HTML.