# Highlight search words

Tags: php, preg-replace

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best way to parse HTML with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-way-to-parse-html-with-php)
>   [PHP Regular expression to match keyword outside HTML tag <a>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7798829/php-regular-expression-to-match-keyword-outside-html-tag-a)

I want to highlight keywords being searched for and have it *not* replace the HTML tags. I used this function but it replaces the links (anchor tags). Is there a way to *highlight* the search terms without creating invalid HTML.

```
function highlightSearch($str,$keyword='')
{
    // $str=text in which I want to search,$keyword is the word which I want to replace.
    $keywords = preg_replace('/\s\s+/i', ' ', strip_tags(trim($keyword))); 
    foreach(array_unique(explode(' ', $keywords)) as $keyword)
    {
        //if(!preg_match("|<[^>]+>(.*)</[^>]+>|Ui",$str))
        $str = str_ireplace($keyword,"<b>".$keyword."</b>",$str);//preg_replace("|($keyword)|Ui", "<b>$1</b>", $str);
        //}
        //$str = str_ireplace( "<b>","<b>", $str);`
        return $str;
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplice of [php regex to match outside of html tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7891771/php-regex-to-match-outside-of-html-tags)