# Regex to match keywords that aren't within <a> tags or alt attribs

Tags: regex, preg-replace

I'm trying to build a regular expression to match keywords in a block of text. These keywords will then have links added to them. Any keyword that is already within a link should not be matched.

I found a post that has got me 90% of the way there - [PHP Regular expression to match keyword outside HTML tag <a>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7798829/php-regular-expression-to-match-keyword-outside-html-tag-a)

The solution allows any keyword within an img alt attribute to match though, breaking the img tags. Is there a way to amend the regex to disallow keywords within alt attributes?

Here's the regex (in PHP) I have now:

```
$content = preg_replace(' ~'.$keyword.'(?!(?>[^<]*(?:<(?!/?a\b)[^<]*)*)</a>)~i', '<a href="'.$url.'">$0</a>', $content);
```

I have an array of keywords/urls e.g.

```
'consectetur' => '/path/to/consectetur'
```

So if I had this text:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
```

The keyword "consectetur" should be replaced with:

```
<a href="/path/to/consectetur">consectetur</a>
```

But not if it appears here:

```
<img src="..." alt="consectetur adipisicing elit">
```

or here:

```
<a href="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

by adding another lookahead after your search term? this is a very convoluted pattern, but seems like it would work:

```
Word(?![^<]*?>)(?!(?>[^<]*(?:<(?!/?a\b)[^<]*)*)</a>)
```

Explanation:

```
Word
(?!         # that is not followed by
[^<]*       # zero or more of anything anything that is not <
?>          # lazily up to >
)           # end lookahead
```

in `<span class="Word">`, `[^<]*?>` matches `">` and fails because of the lookahead.

in `<a href="/Word" alt="Word">`, `[^<]*?>` matches `" alt="Word">` and fails.

this part of the expression i'll leave up to [poster from the thread to which it belongs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7798829/php-regular-expression-to-match-keyword-outside-html-tag-a) to explain, since i'm not totally sure about a couple of the elements in it.

```
(?!(?>[^<]*(?:<(?!/?a\b)[^<]*)*)</a>)
```

Comment: Seems to work, thanks! Could you explain exactly what is happening here? The regex is now not matching keywords enclosed in any tag attribute?

Comment: i've edited my answer to provide an explanation to the best of my knowledge, would be happy to know more if someone cares to elaborate on it